# Share iPhone USB connection through different macs (AWS Instance)

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, macos

There is a way to share my iPhone USB connection to a macOS instance running on AWS?

I need to compile an IOS app to my phone with XCode, but my mac can't update to the latest XCode, so my solution was to use an AWS MacOS instance to build the app (which works), but I need to install it on my phone.

With that in mind, is there a way to share my USB connection to that machine on the cloud?

Comment: Amazon EC2 does not provide this capability. You might be able to use third-party tools like those listed on: [Sharing a USB device with a remote Mac | Mac Mini Vault](https://www.macminivault.com/sharing-a-usb-device-with-a-remote-mac/)